# How to delete a character from a UI Label in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift and I am having issues with deleting a character from a UI Label that I have created. I am trying to make a simple phone dailer app, and I am trying ti implement a backspace button. My UI Label is called DailerLabel, and I know I'm supposed to use the dropLast() function but I keep running into issues about mismatching types or unwrappers. I am not really sure what I am supposed to do here. I tried the thing in the commented code which didn't work, and then I tried what I listed below which doesn't either. Could anyone help me?

```
    @IBAction func backspaceButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (!((DailerLabel.text?.isEmpty)!)) {

       // DailerLabel.text?.substring(to: (DailerLabel.text?.index(before: (DailerLabel.text?.endIndex)!))!)

        let temp = DailerLabel.text
        temp?.dropLast()
        DailerLabel.text = temp

    }
```

Comment: Classes, Structs, and Enums are capitalized. Instance variables are camelCase.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". That's not a useful description. [Edit] your question to clearly specify the exact problem and exact error messages you may be getting from the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, replace label with your own UILabel

```
var name: String = label.text! //shauket , for example 
name.remove(at: name.index(before: name.endIndex))
print(name)    //shauke

label.text = name
print(label.text!)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. dropLast actually returns the string without the last character and you haven't stored that to anything so there is no change. You also have to conver back to String from Substring.

```
@IBAction func backspaceButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (!((DailerLabel.text?.isEmpty)!)) {
        let temp = DailerLabel.text ?? ""
        DailerLabel.text = String(temp.dropLast())
    }
}
```

Here's a better version

```
@IBAction func backspaceButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard
        let text = dialerLabel.text,
        !text.isEmpty
    else {
        return
    }
    dialerLabel.text = String(text.dropLast())
}
```